# Pig JobStats unable to find the output file warning

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, piggybak

I am using Pig 0.11.1 (on CDH4 with MR1) and DBStorage to output aggregated results to MySql2. The job appears to be running fine (finishes successfully and generates an output) but I am getting the warning below. I have done some research but have not been able to understand what the warning means or what impact it may be having. Any information is very appreciated.

> 2014-06-05 06:42:53,189 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.JobStats - using output size reader:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.FileBasedOutputSizeReader
>   2014-06-05 06:42:53,192 [main] WARN 
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.JobStats - unable to find the output
>   file java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   hdfs://ph-task201.mydomain.com:8020/user/V5/ByContentV2 does not
>   exist.    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.listStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:410)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.FileBasedOutputSizeReader.getOutputSize(FileBasedOutputSizeReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.JobStats.getOutputSize(JobStats.java:543)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.JobStats.addOneOutputStats(JobStats.java:567)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.JobStats.addOutputStatistics(JobStats.java:520)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(PigStatsUtil.java:356)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(PigStatsUtil.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:324)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1266)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1251)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1241)    at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:335)     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)     at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)

Answer (score 1):

The warning indicates that you don't have write permission to write to the directory `hdfs://ph-task201.mydomain.com:8020/user/V5/ByContentV2`.